# Parameterization of Google Cloud Build triggered through Git push

Tags: git, google-cloud-build

I have several environment-specific Google Cloud Build triggers, which are set to fire upon Git branch push of my web app code (one for `develop`, one for `staging`, one for `production`).
Each trigger has its own specific substitution variables values, related to the environment the build deploys to.

My build config is defined in a unique `cloudbuild.yaml` file, versioned with the rest of my code in the Git repository. It makes use of substitution variables values defined in each trigger to do environment-appropriate actions.

The build itself is made of several steps, including test steps : back-end tests step, front-end tests step.
Sometimes, I do not want to run front-end tests in the CI (for instance, if my changes are only back-end changes) because it is a waste of time and resources.

I remember when I was using GitLab CI or Jenkins in a previous company that I was able to add a flag to my Git push command to give "options" to the build, such as `--skip-frontend-tests` and they would be transmitted to the build and used as parameters in the pipeline to skip some parts of it.

How could I achieve this while still leveraging Google Cloud Build triggers? Is it even possible?

What I found so far:

- Workarounds using `gcloud builds submit` instead of Git push to start a build but in my case, that would imply a complicated and convoluted set of environment-specific commands instead of the simple and automated Git push with a trigger we currently use.
- Git push options seem to be ignored/unused by Google Cloud Build triggers.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure whether there's a way to access any options that may have been passed to `git push`, but you can access the commit message as shown in [here](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/use-bash-and-bindings-in-substitutions#creating_substitutions_using_payload_bindings), and can use its content to change what happens during the build. This isn't ideal: `cloudbuild.yaml` has no support for skipping steps, so you'll need to add this kind of logic to [scripts](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/run-bash-scripts) within the steps.

There are improvements on the way, but it's going to be a little while.

Comment: Parsing the commit messages and look for a pattern could be a solution indeed, but I wouldn't want to leave "leftover" text which serves no purpose in my Git history, so that would imply re-modifying the commit message after pushing? Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: that's right, as far as I know / can tell. Updating the message after pushing feels nasty, but I'm not sure how these other systems work. Looking at https://docs.github.com/en/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#push (for example), I don't see where that kind of extra metadata would be.

Comment: I can't seem to remember how they did it where I used to work, sorry about that :/
I think it was about parsing Git options but no guarantee: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/push_options.html